# Using maps and enums to manage and store data in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing a mobile app in flutter/dart and I am using Maps and Enums to manage and store data during the app life cycle, is there any performance constraints / gains and what are the limitations.

When I started the app I did not think it thoroughly, and I am not sure now whether I should rewrite the components to use something like sqlite or firebase or just keep doing what I am doing.

The maps mostly used for the data structure.

Sam,

Comment: looking at packages, I am thinking of using hive now https://pub.dev/packages/hive

Comment: It really depends on the data you need to store, and how you will need to access it. For example, if you are storing multiple related data points, and need to be able to search by any of them, a noSQL or other key-value database wont work very well.